# Multiple font sizes in plot title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting in an IPython IDE using `Matplotlib.pyplot` and added a title with:

```py
plt.title('Mean WRFv3.5 LHF\n(September 16 - October 30, 2012)', fontsize=40)
```

However, I want the first line to be size 40 and the second line to be size 18.  Is that possible in `matplotlib`?  I saw the LaTeX use of `\tiny` and `\Huge`, but would like more control.

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.title(r'\fontsize{30pt}{3em}\selectfont{}{Mean WRFv3.5 LHF\r}{\fontsize{18pt}{3em}\selectfont{}(September 16 - October 30, 2012)}')

plt.show()
```

[image: Single label with text of two different sizes.]

That `\r` might want to be a `\n` on your system.

I used [Joel's answer to address your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848503/multiple-fontsize-in-same-label-matplotlib)

Comment: Got error `RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string: 'lp'` in Mac. Seems the [solution is to install texlive-latex-extra](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11357765/3998252). I tried it but didn't work me.

Comment: @JeeYem Seems to be a Mac matplotlib + python problem.Try having a look at this post: https://github.com/dfm/daft/issues/65 .

Comment: `...selectfont{}(September 16...` seems to miss a `{` before `(September...`.

Comment: Or maybe the error is because of: [https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10317](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10317)

Comment: @MaosiChen You were correct about the braces being amiss, but rather than there being a missing brace, there was an extra one: the brace just after `r'`, or rather the one that was there. I've since edited and corrected the code of the original answer.

Comment: It can help to remove problematic characters (like `\r`,`\n`, etc) to get it working, then adapt: i.e. `t = r'\fontsize{30pt}{3em}\selectfont{}{SomeTitle}'` -> `plt.title( t )`

Comment: @pds That is true. However, the real culprit I had had was that I was using the original WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) under Windows 10, which would spit out a huge number of messages when interfaced graphically - which is still not officially supported but works fine. Most of those were inconsequential, but unfortunately, that corresponding error message had gotten lost. However, it was easy to see once WSL 2 was available and I'd updated it.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you may add a **[suptitle](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle)**  or **text** and set at different fontsize like this:

```
plt.title('Mean WRFv3.5 LHF\n', fontsize=40)
plt.suptitle('(September 16 - October 30, 2012)\n', fontsize=18)
plt.text(0.5, 1, 'the third line', fontsize=13, ha='center')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, title and suptitle locates on the same line, that is , they are overlapped. How to control the relative position between them?

Comment: Do you mean you want to separate the lines? You can try using line breaks, that is “\n”

Comment: To be precise, two lines are different objects but it locates on the same position for title and suptitle. But it works. Using "\n" in suptitle, it can locate under title object. That's good technique.

Comment: You can also add a "y" parameter for title or suptitle, indicating its vertical position with 0 --> 1 going bottom --> top: `plt.title(title1, fontsize=12, y=0.95)`

Answer (score 0):

From here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html

You could use it like:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, layout='constrained', sharey=True)
ax1.set_title('damped')
fig.suptitle('Different types of oscillations', fontsize=16)
```

Like this the two different titles should not superimpose on each other.