# Add two titles in python matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, title

If I want to add a tilte to a plot created with matplotlib pyplot in python I use the following command:

```
plt.title('My title', fontsize=20)
```

How can I add two titles, in two different lines, with different font size, in the sames plot? I tried:

```
plt.title('My title', fontsize=20)
plt.tilte('My subtitle', fontsize=15)
```

But the second titled was ignored and only the first one appeared.

Thank you

Comment: Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836048/python-matplotlib-multiple-font-sizes-in-one-label

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName If you find a duplicate, flag it instead of just writing a comment

Comment: @DavidG ok, I didn't know that