# How to set a global subtitle with subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subtitle

How can I set a "global" subtitle when there are subplots?
Here is my best solution, but I need to set a different font size for the subtitle:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.suptitle('Global Title\nGlobal Subtitle.')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple font sizes in plot title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836048/multiple-font-sizes-in-plot-title)

Comment: fig.suptitle('Global Title\nGlobal Subtitle.', fontsize=7)